# Android: Eclipse won't run program onto my device

Tags: android

I plugged in a Nexus 7, downloaded a project I was working on form Google Drive. Now it won't run anywhere, only my other projects which I don't care about. How to get it to run?

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled and does the project work if you plug in a different phone or tablet?

Comment: USB debugging is on, but I don't have any other devices to plug in.

Comment: What do mean by it wont run anywhere. What are the logcat error messages? Is Nexus 7 recognized by Eclipse/DDMS. Hope you have installed the necessary drivers from Asus. http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus+7&p=20&s=16

Comment: Can you run other projects on the Nexus or is it only this one that you can't?

Comment: Whoops! I got it. I went into run configs and messed with some stuff and now I can run it. Thanks anyway!